# I have to send in review my facebook app before this april's end with this login code?

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-login

In my apps i use this methods to log the users with facebook:

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"email"] allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
        if (!error && status == FBSessionStateOpen) {

            action();
        }else{

        }
    }];
```

I can't skip the review process if i use only this method to login? Or i have to send in review anyway the app that use it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to go through the review process if you need additional permissions. The email permission is approved by default.